# jQuery UI Draggable: Custom Snap-To Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, drag

I know the jQuery UI API has `snap`, `snapMethod` and `snapTolerance` built in, but these are not going to work in this case.

Here is the problem I face: when dragging within a container, I want the draggable to snap to the edges of the container when within a certain distance. Calculating distances and triggering this is not an issue. It is getting the draggable to snap which I cannot get to work.

I expected something like: `$draggable.position().left = 0;` might snap it to the left edge of the parent container but it doesn't make any difference.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/jwxrevL2/1/

JS:

```
//set draggable
$('.drag').draggable({
  drag: function(){ drag($(this)) },
  containment: 'parent',
});

//drag
function drag( $draggable ){
  var snap_tolerance = 10;

  //Draggable 
  var d_top     = $draggable.position().top;
  var d_middle  = ($draggable.position().top+($draggable.height()/2));
  var d_bottom  = ($draggable.position().top+$draggable.height());

  var d_left   = $draggable.position().left;
  var d_center = ($draggable.position().left+($draggable.width()/2));
  var d_right  = ($draggable.position().left+$draggable.width());

  //Wrapper 
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  var w_top     = 0;  
  var w_bottom  = $wrapper.height();

  var w_left   = 0 
  var w_right  = $wrapper.width();   

  //snap to left
  if( d_left <= (w_left+snap_tolerance )){
    console.log('snap left');
    $draggable.position().left = w_left; 
    within_snap = true;
  }

  //snap to right
  if( d_right >= (w_right-snap_tolerance)){
    console.log('snap right');
    $draggable.position().left = (w_right-$draggable.width());
    within_snap = true;
  }

  //snap to top
  if( d_top <= (w_top+snap_tolerance )){
    console.log('snap top');
    $draggable.position().top = w_top;
    within_snap = true;
  }

  //snap to bottom
  if( d_bottom >= (w_bottom-snap_tolerance )){
    console.log('snap bottom');
    $draggable.position().top = (w_bottom-$draggable.height());
    within_snap = true;
  }     

}//end fn drag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've have managed to get it working. Although I must say I do not fully understand what is going on. These are the changes I've made ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwxrevL2/2/)):

```
//set draggable
$('.drag').draggable({
  drag: function(e, ui){ drag($(this), ui) },
  containment: 'parent',
});
```

So on the drag event I pass the ui object as well as the jQuery object (I think, please correct me if I am wrong about the ui object) into the `drag` function.

```
//snap to left
if( d_left <= (w_left+snap_tolerance )){
  console.log('snap left');
  ui.position.left = w_left; 
  within_snap = true;
}
```

Then by updating the `ui` objects `position.left` property I can snap it into position.

Can anyone explain why it is different using ui rather than the jQuery object?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

You need to specify a grid like so:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20, 20 ] });
    $( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ grid: [ 80, 80 ] });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3r2xra3/

Comment: Thanks, but the grid solution will not work in the application I am working on.